# How do environments work inside of data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

Within a data.table, I'd like to subset using by= and then have access to an enviroment containing the appropriate column vectors.  However, it doesn't look like it is working correctly.

```
> mtcars
     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
 1: 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
 2: 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
 3: 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
 4: 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
 5: 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
    .
    .
    .

> mtcars <- data.table(mtcars)
> f<-function(e=parent.frame()) {print(ls(e)); 1}
> mtcars[, f(), by=gear]
[1] "Cfastmean" "gear"      "mean"      "print"
[1] "Cfastmean" "gear"      "mean"      "print"
[1] "Cfastmean" "gear"      "mean"      "print"
   gear V1
1:    4  1
2:    3  1
3:    5  1
```

I'd expect that the `print(ls(e))` call would print mpg, cyl, disp, hp, etc.. but it doesn't.  Is there an error here or is this just not how data.table is supposed to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the efficiency tricks of `data.table` is to only put those columns in the environment that are actually used, and you're only using the `gear` column.

Compare with:

```
mtcars[, {.SD; f()}, by = gear]
# [1] "am"        "carb"      "Cfastmean" "cyl"       "disp"      "drat"      "gear"
#     "hp"        "mean"      "mpg"      
# [11] "print"     "qsec"      "vs"        "wt" 
# ...
```

where all of the columns are in the environment, since I used `.SD`.